# Why React Js is not loading external scripts files when route change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using React-Router-Dom-6. my public folder structures are:
[image: here are my js files inside the public folder:]

I have some external javascript libraries for template design in the main public and my index.html is:

```
    <!--=============== scripts  ===============-->
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/babel"></script>
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/js/plugins.js"  type="text/babel"></script>
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/js/scripts.js"  type="text/babel"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

above javascript files are working or loading on the first page when the application gets started. But these libraries are not working when redirecting to another page. at that time route changed but the js files are not loading. I tried many ways but couldn't get the solution. I am using react-router-dom v6 for routing.

Answer (score 1):

You should make use of them in the App.js component, call them with useEffect hook before your render method... this process should work on every route changed

for example:

```
useEffect(() => {
 const script = document.createElement("script");
 script.src = "/path/to/jquery.js";
 script.async = true;
 document.body.appendChild(script);
},[])
```

or this link should do
https://betterprogramming.pub/4-ways-of-adding-external-js-files-in-reactjs-823f85de3668

Comment: this way can add scripts files but these are not loaded when route change

Comment: sorry a mistake to that, if you have a root layout you can put that hook and it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same, so you can load js every time when page is render. You can use this code in App.js component inside useEffect Hook.

Create a one function "loadScript"

```
const { pathname } = useLocation();

var loadScript = function (src) {
   var tag = document.createElement('script');
   tag.async = true;
   tag.src = src;
   document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(tag);
}
```

Call this function inside Hook

```
// Setting page scroll to 0 when changing the route
// You should add multipule script file in this function
useEffect(() => {
   loadScript('/assets/js/plugins/jquery.min.js')
   loadScript('/assets/js/plugins/plugins.min.js')
   loadScript('/assets/js/main.js')
   document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
   document.scrollingElement.scrollTop = 0;
}, [pathname]);
```

This Hook call every time when page change every time

or you should follow this link https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13578